# Add characteristic to with Netlogo procedure

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to run the following Netlogo procedure:

```
to spread-virus
  ask turtles with [infected?]
      [ ask link-neighbors with [not infected?]
        [ if random-float 100 < virus-spread-chance
          [ become-infected ] ] ]
end
```

I'd like to not only `ask turtles with [infected?]`, but also those `with [immune?]`. How can I add a second characteristic (`immune`) in addition to `infected`?

Comment: `with [infected? or immune?]`

Comment: I know this is a pretty minor question. But if you want to put this in an answer I'll select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credit @alan, `with [infected? or immune?]`